# Writing output to a file in python

Tags: python

I am unable to write all values of the output to a file . Kindly help.

```
import numpy as np
theta=10
sigma=np.linspace(0,10,300)
Re=np.linspace(5,100,300)

file = open("New values sigma5.txt", "w")

for i in np.arange(0,300):
    mu=np.sqrt(Re[i]*sigma)
    A=(mu-1)*np.exp(mu)+(mu+1)*np.exp(-mu)
    B=2*mu*(theta-1)
    C=(A/B)


    D1=np.exp(mu)/2*(mu+sigma)
    D2=np.exp(-mu)/2*(mu-sigma)
    D3=mu**2
    D4=np.exp(-sigma)
    D5=sigma
    D6=mu**2-sigma**2
    D7=D3*D4
    D8=D5*D6
    H=D7/D8
    D9=(1/sigma)
    D=D1-D2+H-D9
    K1=C-D
    K2=np.delete(K1,0)
    K3=np.nonzero(K2>0)
    K33=np.array(K3)
    K4=np.shape(K3)
    K5=len(K33.T)
    K6=K5
    K7=sigma[K6]
    K77=np.array(K7)
    print K77

file.write(K77)

print(K77)
file.close()
```

The output is given by K77. By the present form of the code, I am getting to see only the last value of K77. I dont see the other ones.

Comment: K77 is re-assigned in every iteration of the loop. You only write after all iterations are done. So obviously you only see the last value in the file.

Comment: How can I write all the values then? I am unable to figure out with the present version.

Comment: Why would you write your code like this? It's almost like reading some sort of compiler's intermediate representation. There are so many useless variables (e.g. `K6`), the names are meaningless, and practically everything gets its own line. Are you aware you can write complex, meaningful expressions without saving every intermediate result to a variable?

Comment: I have done this primarily to check for errors in each step of the process. Compact forms are good but prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to append the data. try opening the file in [append mode](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) using `a` instead of `w` in

`file = open("New values sigma5.txt", "w")`

Currently you are over writing the file content. Using the append mode, you can append the new data to the file.

The other problem I see is that you may want to save data to the file during every iteration, so `file.write(K77)` should be in the `for` loop.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working. The output when written to a file is a set of absurd characters. I don't even know what they are but very strange.

Comment: What does `print k77` gives?

Comment: In the output window, it gives 100 numeric values which are perfectly fine. However, I am unable to write these 100 values to a file. I am getting characters when I write it to a file like ($ÿ‚µ„¯¹?$ÿ‚µ„¯¹?$ÿ‚µ„¯¹?$ÿ‚µ„¯¹?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­)

Comment: Well your current question is answered. For new questions please ask a new question and provide details.

Comment: It is not answered. As I mentioned, the written file contains absurd characters which I highlighted above.

Comment: Your question is answered, you wanted to save the output to a file, which is done. Also you never mentioned this problem about weird characters in your question. Asking new questions in comments is not an ideal way! Just a guess I think you can use `numpy.savetxt()` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to capture each of the 300 values for K77, you need to change

```
   ...
    K77=np.array(K7)
    print K77

file.write(K77)
....
```

to (notice the different indentation)

```
   ...
    K77=np.array(K7)
    print K77

    file.write(K77)
    ....
```

This will write each line to the file.

Comment: Not working. Appearance of strange characters like $ÿ‚µ„¯¹?$ÿ‚µ„¯¹?$ÿ‚µ„¯¹?$ÿ‚µ„¯¹?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­±?ÃTWÎ­

Comment: I'm not a numpy guy.  But remember that K77 isn't a number, it is a numpy array object.  Maybe someone knows why Print() and Write() would behave differently for that.